# Listing Esmes && restcomm-hlr-simulator

Tags: restcomm

I have two questions about Restcomm SMSC :

Question 1 :

I try to get all Esmes for this I invoke the webservice:

http://localhost:8080/jolokia/read/org.mobicents.smpp:layer=EsmeManagement,name=SmppManagement/Esmes

On the first invocation of the url every thing works perfectly (get all esmes), but when an Esme changes its status (exp : from Bound to closed) and I invoke again the url I get errors like tcpNodelay error or keppAlive error.

How can I fix that ??

Question 2 :

I need the HLR simulator for testing, I found these lines in the Restcomm docs :

"Procedure: Running HLR Simulator
1. Change the working directory to the bin folder for the HLR Simulator.
[vinu@vinu-neha ~]$ cd {this-folder}-smsc-/tools/{this-folder}-hlr-
simulator/bin"

but I can't find the folder restcomm-hlr-simulator in the latest Restcomm release 7.2.0